# Drop Repeated Values in Column, Retaining the Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem similar to dropping duplicates, but I need to retain the row that has the repeated value.  So essentially, I need to retain the first value and then replace every repetition of it with ''.

```
Col1    Col2
a        1
b        1
c        1
d        2
```

What I need is:

```
Col1     Col2 
a        1
b
c
d        2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with replace values to empty string - but get mixed values - numeric with strings, so some functions should failed. Better is replace to `NaN`s, although `integer`s are converted to `float`s.

```
df.loc[df['Col2'].duplicated(), 'Col2'] = '' 
#if want numeric column
#df.loc[df['Col2'].duplicated(), 'Col2'] = np.nan
```

Faster alternative:

```
df['Col2'] = np.where(df['Col2'].duplicated(), '', df['Col2'])
```

---

```
print (df)
  Col1 Col2
0    a    1
1    b     
2    c     
3    d    2
```

Comment: Indeed, but wouldn't it be better to suggest using groupby, which is essentially what OP wants?

Comment: @DeepSpace - `groupby` is nice alternative, but still slowier as `duplicated` vectorized solution.